# Custom SSH password prompt on Linux

Tags: ssh, prompt

I want to modify the ssh (OpenSSH) password prompt on `ssh user@10.1.1.1`
from:

```
user@10.1.1.1's password:
```

to:

```
user's password:
```

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the source code and recompile OpenSSH in order to do that.